# metodo que devuelve un vector en una clase

Tags: c++, array, class

Muy buenas, estoy intentando hacer un método que devuelva un vector introduciendo un string, es decir llamar al metodo con una frase y que este la descomponga en palabras y devuelva un vector compuesto por cada palabra.

Primero limpio la frase con cleanstring, a continuacion la divido en palabras(tokens) con stringstream al mismo tiempo que las voy guardando en el vector con un bucle while , para finalmente devolver el vector. Pero salta error.

Uso GCC, con g++

La clase la llamo Util.
Este es el codigo dividido en Util.cc y Util.h :

-Util.h------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Util.cc-----------------------------------------------------------

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que lenguajede programacion es?

Comment: C++ , perdon por no añadirlo

Comment: Puedes agregar el código como texto no como imagen.

Comment: ¿Qué es extractTokens, una función o un vector? Si es una función, no puedes llamar push_back por ella, ni devolverla como un vector. Quizás necesites dos cosas separadas, un vector y una función.

Comment: Muchas gracias n. 'pronouns' m. ; exactamente era eso, estaba llamando a un vector que no existia, asique tan solo habia que crearlo en la funcion y sacar ese vector creado. Un saludo!